# How to set the focus on a hidden textbox field using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, focus

How can I set the focus on a hidden textbox element?

**I tried this:**

```js
document.getElementById("textControl_fd_component_JSON_TASK_NStext64").focus();
```

But, this does not work here. As `alert(document.activeElement.id);` returns `null` in this case.

If I make this field visible, the above script works fine. Any ideas where I am getting it wrong?

Comment: I think you've just proven that you can't set focus on a hidden field, which makes sense. Can you expand on why are wanting to do this? There might be a better approach.

Answer (score 76):

If you really need to do this, make the box transparent, not hidden:

```
opacity:0;
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
```

Alternatively, if you want to ensure that the user doesn't accidentally click it, just place the input inside a div with

```
width: 0;
overflow: hidden;
```

**However**, there is most certainly a better way to do what you want, maybe using `keydown`/`keypress` events.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you just saved me from hours of struggling :)

Comment: This is good, ideally there would be a `focusable` attribute you could put on undisplayed (`display: none;`) DOM nodes that would allow them to gain focus (regardless of whether there is then any javascript to handle this and make something visible to the user).

Comment: Is there an official reference for this behavior somewhere? Does this apply to `visibility: hidden`, too? Or just `display: none`?

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately this _is_ the best way to receive input. `keydown`/`keypress` events don't cut it for IME input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't  think this is allowed, at least in IE.  I got this information from [jQuery's focus page](http://api.jquery.com/focus/).

Answer (score 0):

You can add some js if you need a workaround and cannot change the opacity attr.

```
/* bind a click handler to your trigger */
jQuery('#your-search-trigger').on('click', function searchIconEventhandler (event) {
    /* in case your field is fading, cheat a little (check css transition duration) */
    setTimeout ( function timeoutFunction () {
        /* show the cursor */
        jQuery('#your-search-input').focus();
    }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Apsillers answer, my setup for this same situation involved:

1. a parent div with position:relative;
2. a child form element position:absolute; z-index:0; opacity:0; filter:alpha(opacity=0);
3. a second child element position:absolute; z-index: (value > 0) (positioned to cover the transparent input).

Aspillers' answer is the correct one given the question asked, but I wanted to give a practical example of when this is necessary.

Specifically, form elements can be hidden if you're using any kind of script/plugin that makes "fancy" inputs (i.e. radio/check elements, select elements). But if your script or plugin is written poorly, it can eliminate keyboard accessibility. Preserving the flow of a form by allowing all elements to have focus can save a lot of headaches for website users.