# Text box Focus, Keep the Focus on text box no matter what in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, focus, barcode-scanner

I have a Bar code Scanning Application where the Scanner is a Plug and Play and decodes spits out the value. What I have is a text box in that is a Auto Post back and as soon as the Scanner scans the ID that goes into the text box and loads data. 
The issue I am having is the text box is invisible and needs to have Focus on it no matter where every I click on the window or even switch tabs it needs to auto focus on it but when I switch tabs it losses focus what can I do here? 
I have used

```
`txtID.Focus();
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            txtID.Focus();

        }`
```

But it still loses focus once its loaded. I am fairly new to c# and wasn't able to find any code that works with this. 
Please let me know if you have any thing.

Comment: There is no point trying to control the focus server side. Focus is a client side concern. You will need to solve this client side (e.g. with JS).

Comment: Have a squiz at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851402/setting-focus-on-hidden-textbox-field-using-javascript .

Comment: Oh  OK thanks for the Info :)